# C++ - Empty std::list begin() and end() are not equal

Tags: c++, list, loops, iterator

I am iterating through a std::list, using the following code:

```
std::cout << "size: " << get_day_entries().size() << "\n";
for (std::list<DayEntry*>::iterator it = get_day_entries().begin(); it != get_day_entries().end(); ++it){
    (*it)->print();
    if ((*it)->get_date()->compare(*date)){
        std::cout << "FOUND: \n";
        (*it)->print();
        return (*it);
    }   
}
```

When the list is not empty, I get undefined behavior; it seem to go past the end of the list.
When the list is empty (size() return 0), it still goes inside the loop and segfault, since it is empty.

Why is it iterating into the list when it is empty ? And why does it seems like it goes out of bound when it isn't ?
`get_day_entries()` return a `std::list<DayEntry*>`.

According to the other answers, the standard of C++ says that for an empty list, `begin() == end()`, but this code doesn't enter the condition for an empty list:

```
if (get_day_entries().begin() == get_day_entries().end())
    std::cout << "EQUALS\n";
```

Here is the code of `get_day_entries()`:

```
std::list<DayEntry*> get_day_entries(){return m_day_entries;}
```

Comment: show definition of `get_day_entries` if this function returns list by value you will get seg fault, because temporary object list is deleted, and your iterators are invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm ***guessing*** (since you don't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that the function `get_day_entries()` returns the list *by value*. Which means you get the beginning and end iterators from *two different lists*.

Comparing iterators from two different containers leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Either save a copy of the list, or make the function return the list *by reference*.

Comment: That was it. Thanks !

Comment: Do you have some guidelines on when I should return a reference of something instead of its value ?

Comment: @user96649 There aren't really any generic guidelines, it all has to be decided on a case-to-case basis depending on how the returned value is used.

Answer (score 1):

It is unsure with the code provided, but I suppose Your function `get_day_entries()` creates new list everytime it is called (for example by returning by value, not by reference). And by doing so, their iterators should **NOT** be compared and may (and most probably won't) give proper result. Comparing iterators from different conatiners leads to **undefined baheviour**.